# What means this regular expression?

Tags: java

Sorry I am new in this and I want to know what means this regular expression ['-] in this case.

```
[a-zA-Z]+(['-][a-zA-Z]+)*
```

(also I want to know what this phrase  says, again I really sorry because for you guys this have to be so easy, but I just learned this few your ago. Thanks!

Comment: do you know what the brackets (`[` and `]`)  do? regex101.com does a pretty good job ob explaining any regex you enter.

Comment: Yeah I know that  brackets means thanks! I will check the page right now

Comment: XavierJC you may find complete documentation on regex [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `['-]` means either a `'` or a `-` character.

See the explanation section on [this wonderful tool](https://regex101.com/r/2f8G18/1).